# How to write secure c network software?

Tags: c

For specific reasons, I need to develop a mini web server in C (running Debian).

As my application is likely to be used from the Internet entirely, I would appreciate some tips to secure this type of application.

More generally, I am interested in everything related to how to develop secure software in C.

Many thanks.

Comment: This is a ginormous topic. SO is meant for small specific focussed questions.

Comment: What's wrong with all the existing web servers?

Comment: The question is brief, which is good, but hard to answer in Stackoverflow's format because it is not very focused.

Comment: The problem is that the most popular web servers fully respects the standard and the IETF. For my work, I have to deviate from standards.

Comment: I wish I could vote to open this question. This is such a useful question. It's so sad that SO isn't more open to exploring great content like this.

Answer (score 3):

A good answer would be too big to fit in this little box.

So the short answer is *start reading a book* to understand how this process works:

[Exploiting Software: How to Break Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201786958)

Answer (score 3):

With great difficulty.

The two biggest issues in C are buffer overruns and double-frees, either of which can allow attackers the ability to run untrusted code on your system. So, number one thing, code defensively! Always check array bounds, NEVER use gets, and make sure that you can visually match all frees with mallocs. In fact, if you can, use a conservative GC like boehm so that you don't have to free at all. Then use tools like Valgrind to analyze your program and hopefully find things you forgot.

Then, since you're writing a webserver, you may be running setuid (if you want to listen on a port <1024) which is also very dangerous since it gives anyone who breaks into your program root. So run as much of your system as possible in a forked process as an untrusted user. This is the next layer of security that will hopefully protect you even if your program has an exploit (which it will).

Also, test test test! One important kind of testing for security is "fuzz testing" -- send random input to your program and see what happens. If your program ever segfaults, you potentially have an exploitable bug.

Comment: Your answer is interesting.  I admit that I have had a bad attitude about garbage collection (GC), feeling that it makes an excuse for sloppy coding.  But, then, I have never programmed a network server, so maybe my bad attitude is a useless prejudice.  If you cared to elaborate a little, I would be interested to read.

Comment: Garbage collection definitely has its pros and cons. The main con in my view is performance -- both memory wise (where you can expect to use 2x the memory you otherwise would) and by the presence of unpredictable GC pauses when your program runs. But in terms of having a better chance of writing correct programs, experience and research have shown that it is a great help. Programs written in a garbage-collected language can look sloppy if you're not used to it (where is the ownership?) but most of the "sloppiness" only matters for memory management, which you don't have to worry about!

Comment: Thank you very much for responding constructively. Your answer really helps. I also hope that people with fixed ideas, will not completely kill the little reputation I have.

Comment: @JoshXoder:  It will be hard on you not to take it personally as a newcomer, but the question really does not happen to follow Stackoverflow's conventions.  By Stackoverflow's practice, users are right to vote *the question* down (one doubts that they voting you down, only the question).